# field/column comparison in Perl

Tags: perl, comparison, field

I would like to compare the values from a column (col1) in one file (file1) against the all records from a column (col1) in another file (file2). My strategy was to read files, for each line in file, split by a tab delimiter and compare the values in two columns. If there is a match, print the certain value from the column in the second file and append it to the last column of the first file otherwise print "not found" and append it to the last column of the first file.
I think my following script is comparing line to line instead of line to all lines in the field and returns errors (Use of uninitialized value $col1[0]...). 
You kind help will be appreciated.

```
open (FILE1, "<", "file1") or die ("Can't open file $!");
open (FILE2, "<", "file2") or die  ("Can't open file $!");
my @data1 = <FILE1>;
my @data2 = <FILE2>;
foreach my $curr_line_1 ( @data1 ) {
    my @col1 = split "\t", $curr_line_1;
    }
foreach my $curr_line_2 ( @data2 ) {
    my @col2 = split "\t", $curr_line_2;
    }
            if ("$col1[0]" eq "$col2[0]") {
                open FINAL, '>>', 'final';
                push(@col1, "$col2[1]");
                print FINAL "@col1\n";
                }
            else {
                open FINAL, '>>', 'final';
                push(@col1, "not found");
                print FINAL "@col1\n";
                }
close(FINAL);
close(FILE1);
close(FILE2);
```

---

```
file1    
1  mary
1  tom
2  john
3  will
4  hugh
5  eddy

file2
2  unit2
3  unitA
5  base

final
1  mary  not found
1  tom   not found
2  john  unit2
3  will  unitA
4  hugh  not found
5  eddy  base
```

Comment: Your question is a little unclear.  File1 contains a lookup table of keys and values. File2 contains rows of data. You want to take each row in File2 and look up a certain column's value in File1 as the key.  If it's found you want to append the corresponding value from File1 to a different column in File2; if not found, you want to append the string "Not Found" to the same column in File2.  Is this correct?  It would be very helpful if you could provide some sample data for File1 and File2, and the expected output.

Comment: You are exactly right. I will provide some sample data right away!

Comment: rookie mistake! I fixed it.

Comment: Now it can't ever be false.

Comment: Hope this makes sense now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think your first for loop is doing anything.  It looks like it's just setting a variable that's local to the loop over and over again.  Do you have 'use strict' on?  You should be getting a warning when it hits $col1[0], because at that point there's no variable with that name in scope.  Maybe instead of using that loop, you could do something like

```
my @data1_fields = map { [ split "\t", $_ ] } @data1;
```

And then handle the comparison in the second loop.

Edit: in fact, the second list would probably be better as a hash, and then that would make everything easier.  Assuming the keys of each row in file2 are unique, maybe try this (untested):

```
my %data2_hash = ();
for (@data2) {
  $data2_hash{$_[0]} = $_[1];
}
for (@data1_fields) {
  # this is bad style, but w/e
  push(@{$_}, $data2_hash{$_[0]}) if exists $data2_hash{$_[0]};
}
open FINAL, '>>', 'final';
for (@data1_fields) {
  print FINAL join "\t", @{$_};
}
```